# User permission is denied with chown using Dockerfile on docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, chown

I'm trying to mount a volume in docker-compose. But it seems my user does not have permission to use volume. :/

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8u181-jdk-slim

ENV HOME /app
ENV CONFIG_PATH $HOME/config
ENV DATA_PATH $HOME/data
ENV LOG_PATH $HOME/log

RUN addgroup --gid 1001 myuser \
    && adduser --uid 1001 --gid 1001 --home $HOME --shell /bin/bash \
        --gecos "" --no-create-home --disabled-password myuser \
    && mkdir -p $CONFIG_PATH $DATA_PATH $LOG_PATH \
    && chown -R myuser:myuser $HOME \
    && chmod -R g=u $HOME \
    && chmod +x $HOME/*


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get clean

VOLUME $CONFIG_PATH $DATA_PATH $LOG_PATH

USER myuser:myuser

EXPOSE 7777
EXPOSE 8080

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=10s --start-period=2m \
    CMD curl -f http://localhost:7777/health || exit 1

COPY --chown=myuser my-service-*.jar $HOME/my-service.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $HOME/my-service.jar $0 $@"]
```

my docker-compose file is:

```
volumes:
    my-service_stream:

    my-service:
        image: my-service-image
        networks:
            - internal
        env_file:
            - config/common.env
        volumes:
            - my-service_stream:/app/data/state
```

not able to use myuser and not able to mount for this user :/. I can not use and myuser does not have permission to write that volume.

I have tried adding user to my docker-compose file as

```
    user: "1001:1001"
```

but nothing is changed.